# How to insert a comma before the last two numbers in the sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the number `1,033.23`, but this number is considered varchar, how do I make it `1033.23`?
The idea I had was:

```
SELECT
REPLACE(column, ',', '')
FROM table
```

but the number `7.22` becomes `722`, how do I make `722` become `7.22` after replaces?

In other words, how to always insert a comma before the last 2 numbers?

Sorry for my bad English, I use google translator

Comment: I suppose the *real* question is "Why are you storing numerical data as a `varchar` in the first place"? Also your title asked how to *add* a comma, yet your question asks how to remove it; 2 completely opposite things.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
select try_convert(numeric(10, 2), replace(column, ',', ''))
```

You can then replace the `.` with a `,`:

```
select try_convert(numeric(10, 2), replace(replace(column, ',', ''), '.', ','))
```

Comment: @DiegoSantos . . . Do your internationalization setting use a comma for a decimal point?

Comment: Yes, i'm Brazil its use

Answer (score 0):

***Depending on your server Thousand Separator setting you may use one of the two cases below:***

```
DECLARE @num NVARCHAR(100) = replace(replace(replace(convert(VARCHAR(30), '1,033.23', 1), ',', '|'), '.', ','), '|', '.')
DECLARE @num_style2 NVARCHAR(100) = replace(replace(replace(convert(VARCHAR(30), '1.033,23', 1), '.', '|'), ',', '.'), '|', ',')

SELECT convert(FLOAT, replace(@num_style2, ',', '')) -- or @num
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a function like this (but remember that there are different decimal/thousand separators among countries) (in Poland "10 000,50", in US it's "10,000.50")

```sql
CREATE or ALTER FUNCTION dbo.utl_f_string_to_number(@string varchar(100))
RETURNS numeric(20,4)
AS
BEGIN
  RETURN TRY_CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(@string, ',',''), ' ','') as numeric(20,4))
END
GO
```

Example with function

```sql
SELECT dbo.utl_f_string_to_number(some_column) FROM some_table
```

Simpler example without a function

```sql
SELECT TRY_CAST(REPLACE('1,033.23', ',', '') as numeric(16,2)) -- 1033.23
```

...or answering question - one could use some combination of `REVERSE`

```sql
SELECT REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(col), 2) -- last 2 chars
       + '.' -- inserted character
       + SUBSTRING(REVERSE(col), 4, 200)) -- first chars without last 3 (decimals + sign)
FROM ( SELECT '1 500,39' [col] ) t
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this case:

```
replace(Convert(numeric(18,2), Substring(replace(column, ',', ''), 0, len(replace(column, ',', ''))-1) + '.' + right(replace(column, ',', ''), 2)),'.',',')
```